# How to set up database with multiple one-to-many relationships? with pivot or join tables?

Tags: mysql, join, pivot, relationship, one-to-many

I'm trying to set up a database, but not sure how I should make the relationships between some tables and my databaseskills aren't that good.

I've got 3 tables , let's say **A**, **B**, **C**.
**A** and **B** have both a **one to many** relationship to **C**, but **C** can only relate to **A** or **B** not both.

Should I make 2 pivot/join tables like **A_C** and **B_C**, but that makes the relationsships **many to many** right?

Or

Should i make a reference-id(FK) in **A** and **B** to **C**, like **C_id**

Or

The otherway around: make a FK **C** to **A** and **B**, although i thought this isn't possible due to the fact that **C** can only relate to only **A** or **C**.

Comment: So can A be related to many C's but C can only be related to one A, or the reverse, where A can only be related to one C but C can be related to may A's? If C can only be related to a single A or B and never be related to A and B, then you would want the FK to be on C with a second column indicating which one it's related to (I think), otherwise there is no way (that I know of) to enforce both the one-to-many relationship and the "either A or B, never both". Basically, it sounds like the "A or B" is a "flexible" relationship (like a related parent) so you would want a generic FK field.

Comment: Yes C can be related to many A's or B's. A and B only relate to one C

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making a new table for A and B instead of just one for both( C)